# Django django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm error during template rendering

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I am implementing a user password reset using django views and I am getting some error with django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm

The link to reset the password comes through e-mail :

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Password reset on 127.0.0.1:8000
From: webmaster@localhost
To: progpyftk@yahoo.com
Date: Thu, 06 Oct 2016 19:01:30 -0000
Message-ID: <20161006190130.10100.76186@PEAMV57.exprogroup.local>


You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user
 account at 127.0.0.1:8000.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/password-reset/confirm/Mw/4fx-63795155cddbbad87a79
/

Your username, in case you've forgotten: Gileno

Thanks for using our site!

The 127.0.0.1:8000 team
```

When I follow the link I got the following error:

TypeError at /account/password-reset/confirm/Mg/4fx-ee6f1fadc877a2279bdc/
string indices must be integers

```
   return get_password_validators(settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py
", line 29, in get_password_validators
    klass = import_string(validator['NAME'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
[06/Oct/2016 16:02:59] "GET /account/password-reset/confirm/Mw/4fx-63795155cddbb
ad87a79/ HTTP/1.1" 500 201517
```

the password_reset_confirm.html

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Reset your password{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Reset your password</h1>
    <!-- We check if the provided link is valid. Django reset password view sets this variable
and puts it in the context of this template. If the link is valid, we display the user
password reset form. -->
    {% if validlink %}
        <p>Please enter your new password twice:</p>
        <form action="." method="post">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p><input type="submit" value="Change my password"/></p>
        </form>
    {% else %}
            <p>The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used. Please request a new password reset.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an invalid `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` setting.  It should be a list of dictionaries. The error message suggests you have a list of strings instead.

The example given [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/passwords/#enabling-password-validation) is:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 9,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured out before seeing your anwser, but you got direct to the point !